# Angular 2 app with PhoneGap module not initializing

Tags: angular, cordova, phonegap-build

I try to build a native mobile app using PhoneGap SDK with Angular 2.
I got the "ng build --prod" output and put it into /www folder of PhoneGap project.

Now on mobile app: PhoneGap Developer, the page is loading but the Angular 2 module is not initiating.
I don't get any errors using the debugging tool: weinre (mentioned here: http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/debugging/)

Do you have any ideas how I get an error?
I already tried "adb logcat" (Android debugging)

The web app is running without any errors accessing the IP-Address with port 3000 directly.

Comment: a. You've tagged this PhoneGap Build and I don't think you're using Build, are you? b. Have you tried chrome inspect whilst your Android phone is plugged into your computer?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I fixed it with changing the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`

Comment: Awesome. Also solves problem with putting app into subfolder on domain.